# is including hardhat's artifacts folder in build files safe?

Tags: solidity, abi, hardhat

I am trying to deploy my DAPP to vercel. it says 'module not found' for the files in artifacts folder. Ofcourse, it is missing because it is included in the `.gitignore` file, so I added the artifacts folder back to my production build now everything works fine.

i jsut wanna knof if it's safe to include that publicly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it should be safe. It only contains the result of compiling your contracts.

The downside of committing that directory is that it can have a large size if you have many contracts. There are some alternatives if you run into an issue because of that:

1. Instead of committing the `artifacts` directory, run `npx hardhat compile` as a preparation step. I'm not very familiar with vercel, but they most likely have some kind of hook for that.
2. Commit the artifacts directory but ignore the `artifacts/build-info` directory, since that's by far the biggest contribution to that directory size. You can do this by replacing `artifacts` with `artifacts/build-info` in your `.gitignore`.